# How is salary a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, expectation, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

In an online course [here](https://youtu.be/pXQnqZlrsXY), the author presents a problem that salary is normally distributed, provides mean and variance.

As per my understanding, when no of Bernoulli trials are sufficiently large we could approximate binomial distribution to normal distribution.

How can Salary be normally distributed? Or with lesser samples/employees, how is it binomial in nature? I could not imagine how Bernoulli trial (which can have only 2 outcomes like H/T fits here)

Comment: In the video it is assumed that the salary is (approximately) normally distributed. This is an assumption only. This might be plausible for large companies or countries. But it should be tested if this is the case. The assumption that the salaries are binomial distribution doesn´t makes sense in my view.

Comment: Assuming salary is normal, how could the underlying discrete phenomenon could be binomial in nature? Or is there any other discrete random phenomenon possible, that also converges to normal, when sufficiently large sample?

Comment: Usually you have more than two different salaries. Consequently the assumption that the salaries are binomial distributed makes no sense. In the video the lecturer just makes an assumption. If it is true in a specific case we don´t know.

Comment: $\text{Or is there any other discrete random phenomenon possible, }$ $\text{that also converges to normal, when sufficiently large sample?}$ Sure if you look at the birth of boys and girls for instance

Comment: @callculus I could ignore he chose a wrong example, but I want to know if there is any rationale behind it, am I missing any other discrete random phenomenon that when no of employees are sufficiently large (or salary as variable?), gives rise to Normal approximation?

Comment: Boy or Girl is another example :), and yes, it is binomial, and very well emerges as normal when population or employees sufficiently large. What might be in case of salary.

Comment: You have to be careful. In case of salary the probability that an employee earns less than x monetary units is not equal for all employees. Therefore you cannot apply the central limit theorem. You can only apply the central limit theorem if the random variables are **i.i.d distributed**. But if you don´t apply the clt you have to assume that the salaries has to be normal distributed. As I has already mentioned this could be more or less the case, but it does not have to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Normal distributions can arise in other ways than as the limit of a binomial.  In classes we are very prone to assume a normal distribution for some quantity because we have lots of theorems and z score tables that work with it.  You should ignore the word salary and think "a random variable with given mean and variance" and prove or compute what you are asked for.

Salaries in particular do not follow a normal distribution.  First, every normal distribution has some support below zero, but negative salaries are not realistic.  Second, the tails are badly asymmetric.  There is a small tail extending a huge number of standard deviations above the mean with many more events than the normal distribution predicts.

Comment: I did not get 2nd stanza. Normal distribution for binomial problem is just approximation, and sufficiently shifted by the mean of the problem, so though X can start from 0, the negative X can be ignored. The only problem is how he could have simply assumed it as Normal (because till earlier class only distributions taught were binomial (discrete) and normal (continous) as approximation of discrete).

Comment: The random variables might  have a solid underlying phenomena (like binomial pattern emergence converging to normal at high n values). Similarly what might for Salary that led to Normal approximation? It is not convincing to just assume normal distribution.

Comment: What I am saying is that the normal distribution is terrible for salaries.  Certainly in the US the mean is below 200k and the standard deviation below 100k.  Things twenty standard deviaions above the mean just don't happen, so nobody should make more than $2.2M$.  What one should do for a real world item is measure the distribution, which we do for salaries.  Then if we want to compute some function of a random salary, use the known distribution.  We certainly do not know enough about how salaries are set to claim something like the central limit theorem leads to normal.

Comment: My concern is not about numbers. Be it any salary range, what would it be its nature as a discrete phenomenon, that when no of employees are sufficiently large, enables us to use Normal approximation. That is where I am lost. For eg, typical coin flip case, it is Head or Tails, that gives binomial emergence as no of flips increase, which eventually conforms to normal approximation. What would be in case of Salary?

Comment: I think the whole basis of the question is flawed.  We can't find a process that makes salaries be normally distributed because they aren't normally distributed.  The author wants to ask a question about the normal distribution and lazily chose salaries as an example.

Comment: Can it be this way? Say we have some unknown distribution in salary. This is our population. Next we take samples from population and calculate mean. The distribution of these samples as sample size increases, can be a normal distribution due to inevitable error/gaps involved in sampling? In that case, with sufficiently large sampling size, we approach population mean?

Comment: You can measure the mean of any distribution that is well enough behaved by taking samples and averaging them.  You can also measure the variance of the distribution that way as long as it is well defined.  It doesn't need to be normal for that, just to fall off fast enough as the value gets high.  If you look at any of the standard distributions-uniform, normal, Poisson, etc. they all have means and standard deviations.  My objection is that we know salaries are not distributed normally, so it is wrong to try to find out why they are.